# Android BluetoothGattServerCallback SIGSEGV

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, segmentation-fault

I have two Android apps, one is my BluetoothLE server the other one is the client. On the client after I have *discovered Services* I use a characteristic to send a message. Something like this:

```
BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = service.getCharacteristic(CHAR_UUID);
characteristic.setValue("START SENDING...".getBytes());
gatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
```

Then on my server the callback method *onCharacteristicWriteRequest* is called. 
Here I just log the message (which works fine) and then set a value in the characteristic and call *notifyCharacteristicChanged*. Something like this:

```
@Override
public void onCharacteristicWriteRequest(BluetoothDevice device, int requestId, 
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, boolean preparedWrite, 
    boolean responseNeeded, int offset, byte[] value) {

    super.onCharacteristicWriteRequest(device, requestId, characteristic, 
        preparedWrite, responseNeeded, offset, value);

    byte[] bytes = value;
    String message = new String(bytes);
    Log.d(TAG, message);

    String someText = "Some Value";
    characteristic.setValue(someText.getBytes());
    bluetoothGattServer.notifyCharacteristicChanged(device, characteristic, false);
     if (responseNeeded) {
            bluetoothGattServer.sendResponse(device, requestId, 
                BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS, 0,null);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I get the following error when the above method returns:

**A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x10 in tid 10460 (Binder_3)**

According to some stackoverflow questions, this error occurs if you try to dereference a null pointer, but none of my variables is null. Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem or at least have a tip on how to debug it?

**EDIT:**

When I comment out the following line of code I don't get this error, so apparently it has something to do with this, but I still don't know what exactly:

```
bluetoothGattServer.notifyCharacteristicChanged(device, characteristic, false);
```

**EDIT 2:**

This is how I configure my characteristic on the server:

```
BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = new  
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic(CHAR_UUID,   
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ |   BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_BROADCAST, 
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE);

BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = new 
    BluetoothGattDescriptor(DESCRIPTOR_UUID,     
    BluetoothGattDescriptor.PERMISSION_WRITE | BluetoothGattDescriptor.PERMISSION_READ);
descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);

characteristic.addDescriptor(descriptor);
bluetoothGattService.addCharacteristic(characteristic);
```

Comment: I think, you have to call `sendResponse` first and afterwards you initiate a notification.

Comment: I will try it, thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same error..

Comment: How is your characteristic configured? Is it configured to send notifications?

Comment: I edited my question. On the client side I call `gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);`

Comment: Can you add `BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY` to characteristic configuration: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html#PROPERTY_NOTIFY

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately without success either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently calling

`bluetoothGattServer.notifyCharacteristicChanged(device, characteristic, false);`

in the `onCharacteristicWriteRequest` callback method causes the problem. Calling it somewhere else works just fine.

It would still be interesting if anyone knows *WHY* it doesn't work.